# Julia "No such file or directory"

Tags: julia

I have some .txt files in a folder that is not the folder where my script is. But when I try to open those files I get `LoadError: SystemError: opening file "/some/folder/filename.txt": No such file or directory`

```
path = "/some/folder/"
files = filter(file -> endswith(file, ".txt"), readdir(path))

for file in files
    open(file, "r")
end
```

If I just do a println(file) in the for loop I can see that the files are there. But if I try to do anything to the files I get this error. I have used pwd() to get the correct directory. Really confused to as I'm getting this error.

Comment: If you use printLn(file), is the output a relative path to $path or an absolute path?

Comment: If I do println(file) in the loop I only get the filename, so I don't get any path at all.

Comment: Yes then that is the case. Try to concatenate file and path to use for the first parameter for function open(). This is because when you running open,  the base directory for your program is not path, it is probably the folder that your Julia file lies in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docstring:

```
help?> readdir
search: readdir

  readdir(dir::AbstractString=pwd();
      join::Bool = false,
      sort::Bool = true,
  ) -> Vector{String}

  Return the names in the directory dir or the current working directory if not given. When join is false, readdir returns just the names in the directory as is; when join is true, it returns joinpath(dir,
  name) for each name so that the returned strings are full paths. If you want to get absolute paths back, call readdir with an absolute directory path and join set to true.
```

i.e. you want `readdir(path; join = true)` to get the full paths to your files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Terminal as part of the editor (at the bottom of the attached screenshot) had a different directory than my currently opened .jl file.
I use VSCode on Linux.
I manually changed the directory in the embedded terminal as part of the VSCode editor in order for julia to detect my file.
[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you changed VSCode extension REPL so that it's in the path of the working directory?

Comment: I didn't change anything for the REPL or VSCode itself. I just realized that since my project folder (folder currently in workspace) was pointing to a different directory, I just used a shell command (entered shell command mode by pressing ';' ) to go to the correct folder, say <cd '../../correctFolder/correctFile.jl>.